# Loop through form checkboxes for dynamic list of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
elm = ('cbProducts' + suffix);
_ctl = document.forms[0].elements[elm];
```

This works when there are more than 1 checkbox in my list.
But when there are only 1, _ctl is undefined.

Would rather use jQuery if possible and have something like:

```
elm = ('cbProducts' + suffix).trim();
_ctl = $("form :input #cbProducts*");
```

Next step is assigning length of _ctl (_ctl.length) but it is null for only 1 checkbox in the elements collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want all inputs whose ids start with `cbProducts`?

```
$("form input[id^='cbProducts']");
```

or do you want inputs with `cbProducts` anywhere in the id?

```
_ctl = $("form input[id*='cbProducts']");
```

and of course `_ctl.length` will give you the number of elements in this set.

---

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, if you know the id you're looking for, instead of this:

```
$("form input[id='cbProducts' + elm]");
```

opt for this

```
$("#cbProducts" + elm);
```

Comment: Start with is the one I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: @Taersious - huh?  So this isn't what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes. You have helped me. Turns out I need to know how to access the other way as well. Something like `$("form input[id='cbProducts' + elm]");`